# CLLocationManager singleton iphone example

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager

I am new to iPhone development,  i am creating a location based app. i have searched lot related to location and came to knew that use one object ( singleton pattern ) of `CLLocationManager` through out app, in my app i have to update user's location to server using web service,

**UPDATE**

as discussion with Umer i came to knew that i can use  one object in appdelegate of `CLLocationManager` and implement delegate methods in that, and update user location to server in app delegate ,

So, is it good to do in appDelegate ??

please help.

Comment: Are you sure, there is no example of it?

Comment: Please go through the link once again clearly show how to make sharedInstance of CLLocationManager.

Comment: @umersufyan: yes, i didnt found any example related to singleton with locationmanger,

Comment: @iPhoneDev: i show that link, it show how to create class, but didnt show how to use it in another viewcontroller,,\

Comment: But it simply provide you the class implementation.Then the class where you want to use simply include the file.Make a instance of the class type.And use the method.I hope you know how to implement.

Comment: i don't know where you understand clearly singleton concept, but here are the steps, 1. make the classes of singleton  2. initiate it in App Delegate so that your services get started, 3. to access it first in any viewcontroller #import that singleton class in Your case it is LocationController.h 4 and just use [LocationController sharedLocationController].location

Comment: thanks, i am trying on it.

Comment: Take the link download sample and see BigBallOfMud  https://github.com/JAgostoni/iOS-Best-Practices

Comment: @umersufyan: thank you very much, but one question is that where to implement code for submit user location to server , is i have to implement in singleton class?

Comment: there are many consideration, if you need continuous location update to server then you can but better way to  do it in AppDelegate to Update your location to server. and you know very well what are your considerations.

Comment: so if i'll do it in `AppDelegate` than i dont have to go for  singletone class? or simply implement cllocationmanager's  method in app delegate? is it good way?? or i can do it in some other way?

Comment: to answer your first question Yes, You can do it without separate singleton class for location, if you are implementing it in APPDelegate (as AppDelegate is also singleton),it is same as to make  a separate singleton class for location, 2. You can also do it in other way.

Comment: is it good way to do in appdelegate method?

Comment: @umersufyan: updated question please check.

Comment: Ohh, Stack overflow only notifies when some one type your name, it depends on your scenario, if you'r not doing much work in APPdelegate, you can do that in AppDelegate, as long as you are talking about good, good is measures in many ways, efficiency, manageable,  and others many factors, for you which one you feel comfortable use that, hope you understand.

Comment: i feel that app should efficienct.

Comment: Use it in AppDelegate..

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the delegate method of locationManager `StartUpdatingLocation` when user moves to `significant distance` & also call the `web-service` for updating User's Location.

Both Task are done in Background mode.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

[SOURCE CODE](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/)

Comment: but how to get locationmanager object in another viewcontrollers?

Comment: i am new to iphone , i dont know very much about it, if there is example its very helpful,

Comment: thanks for reply, but in source code that you give its only about to run Background Location in one viewcontroller , i want user location in multiple viewcontroller, thst why i am search for singleton,
if any example related to singltone location it will very helpful.

Comment: but it will create multiple locationmanager objects :( , i dont want to implement in that way, please provide some tutorial or example related to it. thnks

Comment: but what i show in the Source code is there is no interaction with server, so i am confused where to write code for upload user location to server.

Comment: and in source code the location manager is implemented in onther viewcontroller, so how will get in app delegate?

Comment: no i am talking about appdelegate.m and viewcontroller.m the link of source code you give has implement cllocationmanager object in some other view controller, in my case i think this is not correct way, so please help me.

Comment: Why is this not correct? It just a object & called delegated method, nothing else.

Comment: but i dont want to use that viewcontroller,? rather i want to implement cllocationmanager in appdelegate object.

Answer (score 0):

Your locationservices will run both in foreground and background, but to allow it to run in background (when the app is open and minimized), you need to declare a special background mode in your projects "Plist" file, if I'm not wrong.

The method didUpdateToLocation will give you updates every time there is a significant movement, which you can define and adjust through various settings, such as CLLocationAccuracy (locationManager.desiredAccuracy and locationManager.distanceFilter).

Depending on what desired accuracy you ask, battery main drain quicker or not.

I don't understand what you mean with "web service". These are not web-related, they're native functionalities of iOS.

Comment: thnks for reply,`web service` means i have to update user location to server

Comment: I would call it "server update". Web service usually is something that you "consume".

Comment: sorry for that, if any example related to singltone location it will very helpful.